# How do you upload images to an FTP server within an Android app?

Tags: android, file-upload, ftp

Is it possible to upload an image from my Android application to an FTP server?  The image will have already been captured using the camera.

In a desktop application, we'd use FTP Client to upload any file / image to a live server.  How can we do something similar within our Android application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this it is working fine for me...

```
SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();


                // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
                ftp.connect("server address", 21, "username", "pwd");

                // Set binary mode.
                ftp.bin();

                // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.


                ftp.cwd("path");

                // Upload some files.
                ftp.stor(new File("your-file-path"));              

                // Quit from the FTP server.
                ftp.disconnect();
```

for more info and jar ...http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/